# Groovy Find Index of Element in Map

Tags: dictionary, groovy, indexof

i have the following Groovy Map ,

```
def mymap=["TXT_TXT":1,"IMG_TXT":2,"TXT_IMG":3,"IMG_IMG":4]
```

How can i find index of an element in this map?

Comment: I hope this [Groovy Maps](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps) page will be helpful for future related questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use findIndexOf method as following :

```
def mymap=["TXT_TXT":1,"IMG_TXT":2,"TXT_IMG":3,"IMG_IMG":4]

assert 3 == mymap.findIndexOf{it.key=="IMG_IMG"}

assert 0 == mymap.findIndexOf{it.value==1}
```

Comment: How did you manage to post a question and the correct answer within the space of a minute? I'm calling shenanigans on this.

Comment: @Don I'm not keen on it either, [but it's perfectly acceptable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) according to the SO guidelines

Comment: @tim_yates I don't see how anyone could possibly post a question, discover the solution, and post it within the space of a minute. Unless of course, they already knew the answer when the question was posted, and posted only in the hope of gaining rep. for their ready-made answer? Do you really think a fellow SO user would stoop so low?

Comment: someone broke the spirit of a rule on the internet? Egads, what has humanity come to!